# React Routing With Protected Route and onboarding

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have created a react application which has a Signin and an onboarding process and a dashboard. Onboarding process contains two pages, which are org-creation and invite-member. Sign in is handled by Aws amplify and it has the google sign in as well. The conditions to check when displaying these pages as follows.

**Conditions:**

1. Signin page can be seen by any user.
2. If the Signin user is a new user they have to go through the onboarding process
3. Both the org-creation and invite-member routes are only accessible by logged in users.
4. dashboard page can only be seen by the users who are logged in and who has completed the onboarding process. Which is org-creation and invite-member. if the logged in user hasn't completed the onboarding process they should be navigated to the org-creation page. (onboarding process check will happen through an api call). If user isn't logged in they should navigate to the Signin page.

In order to achieve these conditions, I have created a code like this. The issue which I am having is, After user logged in and navigating to the org-creation page, the content inside in it is not displaying, I am not sure why.

But someone who is not logged in they are being navigated to the Signin and the content inside is displayed as well.

Any specific reason that this happen? Do I need a separate wrapper to check the onboarding is complete or not? I am handling both in same place.

App.tsx

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './routes/Routes';


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Routes. tsx

```
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoutes from './ProtectedRoutes';

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        
        <Route path="login" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route
          path="create-org"
          element={<ProtectedRoutes component={<CreateOrg  />} />}
        />
  <Route
          path="invite-members"
          element={<ProtectedRoutes component={<InviteMembers  />} />}
        />
  <Route
          path="dashboard"
          element={<ProtectedRoutes component={<Dashboard />} />}
        />
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />

      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

ProtectedRoutes.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate , Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  component: React.ReactNode;
}

const ProtectedRoutes: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({component}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [hasCompletedSteps, setHasCompletedSteps] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUser = async () => {
      try {
        const authUser = await getUserAccessToken();
        setIsAuthenticated(authUser ? true : false);
        if (authUser ) {
          const onboardingComplete = await otherService.get('/onboarding');
       

          if (check for the onboarding process) {
            setHasCompletedSteps(false);
          } else {

            setHasCompletedSteps(true);
          }
          setIsLoading(false);
        } else {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };

    checkUser ();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {

    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }


  if (isAuthenticated && !hasCompletedSteps) {    
    return <Navigate to='/create-org' replace />;
  }

  return <>{component}</>;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making your `ProtectedRoutes` component do too much, especially since you have 1 route that needs to be protected under more than one condition. My suggestion would be to split the responsibility of checking authentication and checking onboarding into two separate components.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate , Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUser = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const authUser = await getUserAccessToken();
        setIsAuthenticated(!!authUser);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkUser();
  }, [pathname]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate , Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const OnboardedRoutes = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasCompletedSteps, setHasCompletedSteps] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkOnboarded = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const authUser = await getUserAccessToken();

        if (authUser) {
          const onboardingComplete = await otherService.get('/onboarding');

          setHasCompletedSteps(!!check for the onboarding process);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setHasCompletedSteps(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkOnboarded();
  }, [pathname]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return hasCompletedSteps
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to='/create-org' replace />;
};

export default OnboardedRoutes;
```

```
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoutes from './ProtectedRoutes';
import OnboardedRoutes from './OnboardedRoutes';

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="login" element={<SignIn />} />

      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="create-org" element={<CreateOrg />} />
        <Route path="invite-members" element={<InviteMembers />} />

        <Route element={<OnboardedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>

      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually this worked. Thanks for the code. But had to do a bit of change. The dashboard wasn't displaying when I login in next time. I mean after completing the onboarding process and go to the dashboard. Then sign out and log back again. Which should technically display the dashboard. but it didn't display the component. I have to put the  `<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />` inside the `<Route element={<OnboardedRoutes />}>` , which made it work
@drew-reese

Comment: @LearnThings I see, sorry, I only had the information you had provided, but glad it is working for you now. Cheers.